Git’s include.path configuration not working as expected
I'm trying to use Git's include.path configuration option to include additional configuration files. However it doesn't seem to work as expected.
Configuration files:
File: ~/.config/git/nested-config
[user]
    name = xyz

File: ~/.config/git/config
[include]
        path = nested-config
[core]
        editor = emacs

bash
bash$ git config --global core.editor
emacs
bash$ git config --global user.name

The second command does not print "xyz" as expected. It prints nothing.
Also tried,
since git include.path supports ~, I also tried the following configuration but encountered same issue.
File: ~/.config/git/config
[include]
        path = ~/.config/git/nested-config
[core]
        editor = emacs


git config --global --show-origin core.editor ? git config --global --show-origin include.path ?

git config --global --show-origin core.editor gives /home/<user>/.config/git/config emacs.  git config --global --show-origin include.path gives /home/<user>/.config/git/config nested-config. git config --global --show-origin user.name prints nothing.  where  is my username.

The first 2 are ok. The 3rd one is strange.

**I was able to figure this out with the help of the helpful people on the #git IRC channel.
Basing on
       --[no-]includes
           Respect include.*  directives in config files when looking up
           values. Defaults to off when a specific file is given (e.g., using
           --file, --global, etc) and on when searching all config files.

git config --global --include user.name should give you your expected results
Probable reason for this behavior is to avoid potentially confusing results when trying to investigate a given scope in isolation.
